# Questions about PDM MEMS microphones

Tags: stm32, microphone, i2s, pdm

I am using STM32F407 Discovery Board for my audio project. There is a PDM mems microphone on this board. I want to get sound signal over I2S with DMA. For that I am using SWV graph in İDE. I tried all I found on the internet. I have a few questions to make sure I am right. I think I need to convert PDM data to PCM for meaningful graph. Is that right? I actually used the pdm2pcm library to do that. But all I get is random numbers, it seems. Then, I try to observe the PDM signal with oscilloscope. The data signal was coming in two voltage levels. Is that normal for the PDM signal?

[yellow signal is I2S CK(pb10), Cyan signal is data(pc3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJZiv.jpg)
[image is taken at start of the run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmbsR.png)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6KPP.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kagk8.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI2tI.png)

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "adc.h"
#include "crc.h"
#include "dma.h"
#include "i2s.h"
#include "pdm2pcm.h"
#include "gpio.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#define ARM_MATH_CM4
#include "arm_math.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */
arm_rfft_fast_instance_f32 fft_instance;

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

#define FFT_SIZE  1024
#define BUFFER_SIZE (FFT_SIZE*2)
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint32_t ADC_Double_Buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
float FFT_InBuffer[FFT_SIZE];
float FFT_OutBuffer[FFT_SIZE];
float FFT_Mag[FFT_SIZE/2];

uint32_t Peak_Frequency;
uint32_t Peak_High_Frequency;

uint8_t Data_Ready = 0;

static volatile uint32_t *FFT_HalfBufferPtr;


uint16_t I2S_Double_Buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
uint16_t I2S_PCM_Double_Buffer[16];

uint16_t pdmdata;
uint16_t pcmdata;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void Process_Data(void);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
uint32_t PDM_Filter(void *pDataIn, void *pDataOut, PDM_Filter_Handler_t *pHandler);
void HAL_I2S_RxCpltCallback(I2S_HandleTypeDef *hi2s);
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_I2S2_Init();
  MX_CRC_Init();
  MX_PDM2PCM_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  //PDM_Filter_Init(&PDM1_filter_handler);

  arm_rfft_fast_init_f32(&fft_instance, FFT_SIZE);
  //HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *)ADC_Double_Buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

  HAL_I2S_Receive_DMA(&hi2s2, (uint16_t *)I2S_Double_Buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);




  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
//    if(Data_Ready){
//      Process_Data();
//    }
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 168;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
//void HAL_ADC_ConvHalfCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hadc){
//
//  if(hadc == &hadc1){
//      FFT_HalfBufferPtr = &ADC_Double_Buffer[0];
//      Data_Ready = 1;
//  }
//}
//void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hadc){
//
//  if(hadc == &hadc1){
//
//
//      FFT_HalfBufferPtr = &ADC_Double_Buffer[BUFFER_SIZE/2];
//      Data_Ready = 1;
//  }
//
//}

void HAL_I2S_RxCpltCallback(I2S_HandleTypeDef *hi2s){
    if(hi2s == &hi2s2){
        pdmdata = I2S_Double_Buffer[0];
        PDM_Filter(&I2S_Double_Buffer[0], &I2S_PCM_Double_Buffer[0], &PDM1_filter_handler);
        pcmdata = I2S_PCM_Double_Buffer[0];

    }
}

void Process_Data(void){
    for (int n = 0; n < FFT_SIZE; n++) {

        FFT_InBuffer[n] = ((float)FFT_HalfBufferPtr[n])/5000.0f;
    }
    arm_rfft_fast_f32(&fft_instance, FFT_InBuffer, FFT_OutBuffer, 0);
    arm_cmplx_mag_f32(FFT_OutBuffer, FFT_Mag,FFT_SIZE/2);
    FFT_Mag[0]=0;

    float Mag_Max = FFT_Mag[0];
    int32_t Mag_Max_İndex;
    for (int16_t i = 1; i < FFT_SIZE/2; i++){
        if (FFT_Mag[i] > Mag_Max){
            Mag_Max = FFT_Mag[i];
            Mag_Max_İndex = i;
        }
    }
    Peak_Frequency = Mag_Max_İndex * 42424.2f / FFT_SIZE;

    Mag_Max = FFT_Mag[170];
    for (int16_t i = 171; i < FFT_SIZE/2; i++){
        if (FFT_Mag[i] > Mag_Max){
            Mag_Max = FFT_Mag[i];
            Mag_Max_İndex = i;
        }
    }

    if(Mag_Max_İndex != FFT_SIZE/2 - 1 && Mag_Max > 0.4)    Peak_High_Frequency = Mag_Max_İndex * 42424.2f / FFT_SIZE;

    else Peak_High_Frequency = Peak_Frequency;


    Data_Ready = 0;


}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

I started this project with an analog mic. It was success. The ADC codes not necessary for I2S.